# Can Somebody Explain this java code

Tags: java, android

I'm just starting out on android and my java is verry rusty. I can't remember ever seeing a function nested in another function like this before. Could somebody explain to me exactly what final does and explain why you would nest a function in another like this?

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(final Message msg) {
            Log.v(Constants.LOGTAG, " " + ReviewList.CLASSTAG + " worker thread done, setup ReviewAdapter");
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            if ((reviews == null) || (reviews.size() == 0)) {
                empty.setText("No Data");
            } else {
                reviewAdapter = new ReviewAdapter(ReviewList.this, reviews);
                setListAdapter(reviewAdapter);
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

- This is an [Anonymous Class](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm). 
  What is actually happening is that a
  subclass of `Handler` is being
  created with an overridden
  `handleMessage` function.

  > One of the most elegant things about
  >   anonymous classes is that they allow
  >   you to define a one-shot class exactly
  >   where it is needed. In addition,
  >   anonymous classes have a succinct
  >   syntax that reduces clutter in your
  >   code.
- You also asked "Could somebody
  explain to me exactly what `final`
  does".  A nice explanation [can be
  found here](http://www.codeguru.com/java/tij/tij0071.shtml).

  In the case of your example the `final` keyword stops anybody from being able to assign a new instance / null the instance of the variable "handler" meaning I cannot write the line `handler =
  null;` or `handler = new Handler() {
  ... }` after your example code snippet.

Answer (score 8):

It seems that I wrote that Java code ;). That's from one of my examples in the Manning book Unlocking Android - http://code.google.com/p/unlocking-android/. While the goal of the book was not to cover Java in detail, and rather to focus on Android, I apologize if it caused confusion.

The answers here are spot on, that's intentionally an anon inner class because it not used anywhere else outside of that context.

One note that I would add though, if you are just starting out with Android, I would go with a newer book. Mark Murphy's CommonsWare books are quite good (http://commonsware.com/Android/) and he keeps them very up to date (or maybe look at Unlocking Android Second edition, I am not involved with that, and haven't read it so can't recommend or not, but Manning is working on it and it is available as early access at their site).

It might seem strange for an author to be recommending a book other than his own, but the truth is there are some better ways to do that stuff now on the newer APIs (that was written at 1.0 level, and tested on 1.5 after the fact). Don't get me wrong, that book still has a lot of value (that I am proud of) in terms of overall concepts (life cycle, activities, intents, etc.), but there are better/easier/newer ways to get some specific tasks done.

For example, have a look at AsyncTask (http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html) and it will save you a lot of Handler/Message pain.

(I would have commented here, but I can't figure out how to comment rather than "answer," it may be related to not having enough of a rep?)

Comment: Yep, you need 50 rep to post comments (and I see that you just hit that threshold :) ).  FWIW, I think this is a fine answer.

Comment: Hi,

Your book is great! I found it much easier to follow than a lot of the other android books. Hope you dont mind me posting your code too much! :) Im basically just going through all the examples and disecting all the bits I don't understand

Comment: I don't mind at all, glad you like it, and thanks! 

I think a lot of the stuff in there is core/fundamental and of course still applies (we tried to write it that way intentionally). Just keep in mind when using it that it's a bit older and the platform has evolved. It can certainly help with understanding and such, but for production code for example, I'd go with the newer constructs (in that case, AsyncTask).

Also, not to pimp it here, but just to let you know, I am working on an updated book. Early stages, but "Android in Practice" is underway.

Answer (score 3):

This is known as an anonymous class.  A detailed explanation available here....[(link)](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm)

Answer (score 2):

This code creates an instance of class Handler,  and at the same time overrides the "handleMessage" method of Handler.

Answer (score 2):

This is an anonymous class which (a) implements the Handler interface or (b) extends the Handler class.